# Share resource with widget using framework in iOS 8

Tags: ios, core-data, ios8, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

I have an app with Today extension.

I have CoreData related code and preloaded .sqlite database in a Framework.

I need to get URL for that .sqlite resource from both app and widget to save it to  Application Group Container.

Something like this:

```
let url = NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.com.ysoftware.Anecdotes")!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("db.sqlite")
    if (!NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(url.path!)) {
        let preloadedStorePath = NSBundle.bundleWithIdentifier("company.Framework").pathForResource("db", ofType:"sqlite") //this line 
        NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(defaultStorePath!, toPath:url.path!, error: nil)
    }
```

Can I do that and how?

Comment: So I had this **database.sqlite file 6.5MB of size.** I managed to access it from app and widget by **setting the target membership for both**. But I didn't want to have a duplicate file especially since it's the biggest file in my project. While making an archive for iTunes Connect, **Organizer estimated the package size to be 21MB** which was disturbing. *Also, if I were to turn off membership for one of those targets, estimaded size went down to 15MB.* I didn't have anything unusual with review but **on the App Store page it says 6.9MB**. It feels like the answer, but I can't be sure.